# Pretty print table with awk

Tags: awk, formatting, tabular

I want to print a table that looks like this:

```
> field1 field2 field3 field4    
> 11.79     7.87    11.79    68   
> .. more numbers
```

How can I arrange it that the captions for the columns are arranged in a way that
puts them on top of the respective column?

```
> field1    field2  field3   field4       
> 11.79     7.87    11.79    68
> .. more numbers
```

My generating script looks like this:
capture.sh:

```
  echo 'field1, field2, field3, field4'
  awk '/Capture the tablestuff/{set variables}
  /DONE/ { printf("%5d %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f \n" ,field1, field2, field3, filed4); '
```

I really would like to refrain from ascii-formatting the echo command if I can.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

How about this one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf("%s %8s %8s %8s \n" ,"field1", "field2", "field3", "field4")}
{printf("%6.2f %8.2f %8.2f %8.2f\n", $1, $2, $3, $4)}' input

field1   field2   field3   field4 
 11.79     7.87    11.79    68.00
 11.79     7.87    11.79    68.00
 11.79     7.87    11.79    68.00
 11.79     7.87    11.79    68.00
```

I.e. using `BEGIN` to print the header, and then print each line formatted according to the printf, with all the numbers in the `input` file, here assuming 4 on each line and nothing else. Tweek it to your needs...

Comment: Using `awk`, how can we ensure that the column width will fit any arbitrary-length string?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez -- post a new question. But you can do a double pass of the data. 1st pass you calculate the maximum width, 2nd pass you print the data using the width from first pass. 3rd option is to use big enough width. 4th is to generate a csv-file instead and use that one instead in e.g. spreadsheet or using python and the csv-module etc. Also, have a look at the `column` program. Do a ^man column`

Comment: @Fredrik Pihl  Hi, I wanted to tabulate some information that are stored in the global variables. How can I use this variables in the above **awk** command to get printed in tabular format.

Comment: @runner -- do you mean `a="a b c d" ; awk '{print $1}' <<<$a`? Using bashs *here-document*. If not, please post a new question since this one is rather old...

Answer (score 37):

> How can i arrange it that the captions
>   for the colums are arranged in a way
>   that puts them on top of the
>   respective column?

Use `column`.

Example from the [man](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/column/) page:

```
   (printf "PERM LINKS OWNER GROUP SIZE MONTH DAY HH:MM/YEAR NAME\n" \
   ; ls -l | sed 1d) | column -t
```

Comment: Didn't know about it yet. Thanks a lot for this great hint!